# Acumatica and Authorize.net and EMV Reader

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know if it's possible to use an EMV reader with the Authorize.net/Acumatica integration? We are on 2019 r1 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yest, it's possible, but with using some technique, similar to Device hub of Acumatica. On machines, where users will use EMV you'll need to have app running in the background, and process EMV requests, and send them to Acumatica.
Another approach would be to consider in-house hosting of Acumatica instead of the cloud. In that case you can send requests from Acumatica directly to EMV devices and process input/output from them.